# Gradle Composite Project: "Could not resolve" even with correct paths

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, composite

When loading a composite project in gradle there is the error:

```
Could not resolve de.demo.project.
Required by:
    project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

settings.gradle.kts:

```
rootProject.name = "demoname"

includeBuild("../other-demo-project")
```

gradle file:

```
....
dependencies {
    implementation(group = "de.demo", name = "other-demo-project")
}
....
```

Paths are setup correctly even, if they aren't there is a `could not find` error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it myself already, so answering for anyone in need and to save hours of frustration.

It was caused by a `java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` in the parent project, that was missing in the child project.

after adding that everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me :

update

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

to

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: Working on a multi-module project with just the 'groovy' plugin, this also was the solution for me because Gradle defaults projects to the version of Java on the path, which for me is 17, but the consumer module was configured to target 8. So the provided groovy module was defaulting to 17. This is not obvious at all until you run gradle with '--info' because without it you just get 'could not resolve' and thats it. Thanks gradle...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you didn't specify the version of the dependency in:

```
implementation(group = "de.demo", name = "other-demo-project")
```

So gradle wasn't able to find the dependency.

You need to add a version like:

```
implementation(group = "de.demo", name = "other-demo-project", version = '???')
```

Then make sure the dependency lives in one of the repositories you have in your repository block

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   ...
}
```

Comment: This would be true for normal dependencies. But `other-demo-project` is an included build (a composite project) that should substitute `de.demo:other-demo-project` (assuming it defines the same group). So no version or repository is necessary. According to the other answer, the issue is that it could not select a variant that fulfilled the requirements for Java 8 compatibility. The error message could be a lot better though :/